# Why is awaiting a coroutine considered non-blocking?

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency

FWIU, if you call `await` in a coroutine, it *pauses* the execution of the coroutine until it completes and "passes control back to the event loop to do other things".

1. Why is this still considered asynchronous if it has to wait?
2. What does "passing control back to the event loop" mean exactly? It doesn't mean that print statement after the `await resp.json()` below can go ahead and execute right?

Below are code snippets from https://www.twilio.com/blog/asynchronous-http-requests-in-python-with-aiohttp

Asynchronous code for 150 GET requests

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

start_time = time.time()


async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        for number in range(1, 151):
            pokemon_url = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{number}'
            async with session.get(pokemon_url) as resp:
                pokemon = await resp.json()
                print(pokemon['name'])

asyncio.run(main())
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

asyncio.run(main())
```

Syncronhous code for 150 GET requests

```
import requests
import time

start_time = time.time()

for number in range(1, 151):
    url = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{number}'
    resp = requests.get(url)
    pokemon = resp.json()
    print(pokemon['name'])

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

The first is a significant performance improvement but I'm not really grasping the concept of how it works if the calls still wait for each response.

Comment: I haven't done a lot with asyncio, but from skimming the doc on `async with` it sounds like that gets you an async context -- I assume that your main loop continues while that context is executing, and starts another async context.  The `await` blocks execution within that particular context, but doesn't block other contexts, so they're all able to execute simultaneously (technically, interleaved) rather than each waiting on the one before it to complete.

Comment: It might also be that I'm misunderstanding the `async with` doc and the performance improvement you're getting is from the fact that in your first block of code you're using a single session (which does some fancy connection pooling stuff on the backend to decrease latency, IIRC) whereas in your second block you're implicitly opening a new session for each `get` call.  You might try changing your second block to use a single `requests.Session` and see how the performance is affected.

Comment: if I use `session = requests.Session()` and later `with session.get(..) as resp:` (without `async`) then second version can work with the same speed. `await` can be more useful if you will run `get()` in separated async function - and then `await resp.json()` will wait for result but at the same time it may run another function which will read another url.